# Optical scattering Vs size of wavelength

Tags: optics, scattering

I am having trouble understanding the my slide was given in my lectures in intro to optics.

[image]

The reason when why I am having trouble is because when I went to research more about each scattering, I cam across the wiki page expaling the Rayleigh scattering and the Mie scattering, but I cant seem to find anything on the middle scattering.

Is the middle referring to what is known as geometric scattering?

Answer (score 1):

If we assume spherical particles it should be mie scattering when the circumference of the particle is roughly the same as the wavelength, rayleigh when the particle is small compared to the wavelength and when the particle is large relative to the wavelength we've got geometric scattering. What is the source of your picture?

Comment: Source is my lecture slides. The course is dealing with medical optics but this was like the introduction.

Comment: @james2018 Yes, i understood that, i was wondering however if there was a source given on the slides? Because the slides don't seem to agree with other sources.

Comment: Ah sorry I miss read, no there was no source, as far as I know. I agree they disagree with other sources, Iv looked in several books and website all which contradict the information present in the slides.

Comment: I'd guess it's safe to assume they're faulty and to proceed with the other sources you've found if you Think they're credible.